# Add Maven dependencies to local repo from a folder

Tags: java, maven

I have a folder containing libraries which I ripped from a Maven repository and need to be able to load them into my local repository. Because they were extracted from Maven using the dependency:copy-dependencies goal they all have their artifact and version number as part of the file name. Most of these a proprietary libraries so I cannot just fetch them again from a global repository.

Any Ideas?

JLove

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking how to intall them in your local repo, or how to make them available to maven from the project? If the former just look at the docs for mvn install:install:file if the latter I wrote a blog post on a way to package project local maven dependencies http://codeghost.co.uk/blog/2012/8/15/environment-agnostic-non-public-maven-library-references.html

Comment: I'm asking how to install them to my local repo, probably should have said that my main reason for the question is the volume of libraries (100+) which is the main issue... I think I'll just write a shell script. Thanks

Comment: The project local repo could still be a quick win for you then. Assuming you don't care what the group id of the artifacts is, you can make a single folder structure with just the final artifact id being different. You can then update your exiting dependencies to use your new details. The libs will get installed into your local repo using the new structure when you run mvn install

Answer (score 0):

Best things for such purposes is to install a [repository manager](http://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html) and install such kind of libraries into the repository manager. Afterwards you can use them as usual dependencies.